# Find array fields sum using lodash or underscorejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have a requirement to find the sum of "count" fields for each "type". 
Is there any way to do the same using lodash or underscore js. 
Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

**Input array**

```
array = [
    {
        type: 'weibo',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'xing',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'twitter',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'twitter',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'facebook',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'facebook',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'facebook',
        count: 1
    }
]
```

**Expected output**

```
 output = [
        {
            type: 'weibo',
            count: 1
        },
        {
            type: 'xing',
            count: 1
        },
        {
            type: 'twitter',
            count: 2
        },  
        {
            type: 'facebook',
            count: 3
        }  
    ]
```

Comment: @RuneFS I see you're plying your wares again ;-)

Comment: :) well it was made for stuff like this. Though the comment was incorrect because I presumably can't read and understand at the same time today...
and seeking both usage and feedback is the best way to improve that I know of :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `_.countBy()` and `_.map()`; note that, due to the midway conversion into an object, the order of the output array may not be the same.

```js
var array = [
    {
        type: 'weibo',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'xing',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'twitter',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'twitter',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'facebook',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'facebook',
        count: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'facebook',
        count: 1
    }
  ];

console.log(_.map(_.countBy(array, 'type'), function(value, key) {
  return {
    type: key,
    count: value
  };
}));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one pass (as usual) with `_.reduce` and `_.values`:

```
var sums = _(array).reduce(function(memo, e) {
    if(!memo[e.type])
        memo[e.type] = { type: e.type, count: 0 };
    memo[e.type].count += 1;
    return memo;
}, { });
var what_you_want = _(sums).values();
```

Or if you want to skip the `_.values` call, you can keep track of the ongoing sums in an object (indexed by type) and an array (what you're actually after) and share the `{type: ..., count: ...}` references between them:

```
var sums = _(array).reduce(function(memo, e) {
    if(!memo.by_type[e.type]) {
        memo.by_type[e.type] = { type: e.type, count: 0 };
        memo.values.push(memo.by_type[e.type]);
    }
    memo.by_type[e.type].count += 1;
    return memo;
}, { by_type: { }, values: [ ] });
var what_you_want = sums.values;
```

That latter approach guarantees that the output order will match the input order.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hgnz04bd/